# I was creating a recycler view and this pop up:

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview

```
2019-11-17 18:31:03.218 22198-22198/com.example.musicmates W/FirebaseRecyclerAdapter: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Firebase Database error: Permission denied
        at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError.toException(Unknown Source:26)
        at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.onCancelled(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:122)
        at com.firebase.ui.database.ObservableSnapshotArray.notifyListenersOnCancelled(ObservableSnapshotArray.java:116)
        at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseArray.onCancelled(FirebaseArray.java:144)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.px.zza(Unknown Source:2)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.vh.zzHX(Unknown Source:4)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.vp.run(Unknown Source:71)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
2019-11-17 18:31:03.219 22198-22198/com.example.musicmates W/FirebaseRecyclerAdapter: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Firebase Database error: Permission denied
        at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError.toException(Unknown Source:26)
        at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.onCancelled(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:122)
        at com.firebase.ui.database.ObservableSnapshotArray.notifyListenersOnCancelled(ObservableSnapshotArray.java:116)
        at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseArray.onCancelled(FirebaseArray.java:144)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.to.zza(Unknown Source:2)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.vh.zzHX(Unknown Source:4)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.vp.run(Unknown Source:71)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
2019-11-17 18:31:03.284 22198-22225/com.example.musicmates W/SyncTree: Listen at /Users/bSct8nl961Pf9N9Napf68m6hAzZ2 failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied
```

**And these are my code**

```
package com.example.musicmates;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestOptions;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;

import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.Set;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private NavigationView navigationView;
private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
private RecyclerView postList;
private Toolbar mToolbar;
private CircleImageView NavProfileImage;
private TextView NavProfileUserName;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private DatabaseReference UsersRef, PostsRef;
private ImageButton AddNewPostButton;
String currentUserID;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigaition_view);
        postList = findViewById(R.id.all_users_post_list);
        postList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

        linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        // set post from latest to oldest
        postList.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


        currentUserID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        UsersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
        PostsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Posts");


        mToolbar = findViewById(R.id.main_page_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home");

        AddNewPostButton = findViewById(R.id.add_new_post_button);

        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawable_layout);
        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(MainActivity.this,drawerLayout,R.string.drawer_open,R.string.drawer_close);
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        View navView = navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.navigation_header);
        NavProfileImage = navView.findViewById(R.id.nav_profile_image);
        NavProfileUserName = navView.findViewById(R.id.nav_profile_full_name);

        UsersRef.child(currentUserID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
            {
                if(dataSnapshot.exists())
                {
                    if(dataSnapshot.hasChild("fullname"))
                    {
                        String fullname = dataSnapshot.child("fullname").getValue().toString();
                        NavProfileUserName.setText(fullname);
                    }
                    if(dataSnapshot.hasChild("profileimage"))
                    {
                        String image = dataSnapshot.child("profileimage").getValue().toString();
                        Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(image).into(NavProfileImage);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Profile name do not exists...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });




        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
                UserMenuSelector(menuItem);
                return false;
            }
        });
        AddNewPostButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               SendUserToPostActivity();
            }
        });
        DisplayAllUsersPosts();

    }

    private void DisplayAllUsersPosts() // retrieve all posts from Firebase Database
    {
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Posts,PostViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Posts, PostViewHolder>(
                Posts.class,
                R.layout.all_posts_layout,
                PostViewHolder.class,
                PostsRef
        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(PostViewHolder viewHolder, Posts model, int position)
            {
                viewHolder.setFullname(model.getFullname());
                viewHolder.setTime(model.getTime());
                viewHolder.setDate(model.getDate());
                viewHolder.setDescription(model.getDescription());
                viewHolder.setProfileimage(getApplicationContext() , model.getProfileimage());
                viewHolder.setPostimage(getApplicationContext(),model.getPostimage());
            }
        };
        postList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    }

    public static class PostViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        View mView;
        public PostViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView)
        {
            super(itemView);
            mView = itemView;
        }
        public void setFullname(String fullname)
        {
            TextView username = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_user_name);
            username.setText(fullname);
        }
        public void setProfileimage(Context ctx ,String profileimage)
        {
            CircleImageView image = (CircleImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_profile_image);
            Glide.with(ctx).load(profileimage).into(image);
        }
        public void setTime(String time)
        {
            TextView PostTime = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_time);
            PostTime.setText("   " + time);
        }
        public void setDate(String date)
        {
            TextView PostDate = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_date);
            PostDate.setText("   "+ date);
        }
        public void setDescription(String description)
        {
            TextView PostDescription = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_description);
            PostDescription.setText(description);
        }
        public void setPostimage(Context ctx, String postimage)
        {
            ImageView PostImage = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_image);
            Glide.with(ctx).load(postimage).into(PostImage);
        }
    }

    private void SendUserToPostActivity()
    {
        Intent addNewPostIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,PostActivity.class);
        startActivity(addNewPostIntent);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if(currentUser == null || currentUserID == null){
            SendUserToLoginActivity();
        }
        else{
            CheckUserExistence();
        }
    }

    private void CheckUserExistence()
    {
        final String current_user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

        UsersRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
            {
                if(!dataSnapshot.hasChild(current_user_id))
                {
                    SendUserToSetupActivity();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }

    private void SendUserToSetupActivity() {
        Intent setupIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SetupActivity.class);
        setupIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(setupIntent);
        finish();
    }

    private void SendUserToLoginActivity() {
        Intent loginIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
        loginIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(loginIntent);
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        if(actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void UserMenuSelector(MenuItem menuItem) {
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
            case R.id.nav_post:
                SendUserToPostActivity();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_profile:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Profile", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_home:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Home", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_friends:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Friends", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_find_friends:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Find Friends", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_message:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_setting:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Setting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_logout:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Log out", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mAuth.signOut();
                SendUserToLoginActivity();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to enable rules to `true` at Firebase Database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change security rules on your firebase database:

[image]

The easiest option is to set for everyone read & write access to true:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

But you can set here more complicated rules too. More in docs - [Firebase Security Rules.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules)

Answer (score 0):

You have to grant `.read` access to your firebase database.

Go to rules tab in your firebase console and enable `.read / .write` permission

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, in order to easily develop with Firebase, data permissions can initially be enabled by editing the rules file in firebase console.

Firebase -> Console ->  -> Database -> rules:

```
{
  // Allow read/write access to all users under any conditions
  // Warning: **NEVER** use this ruleset in production; it allows
  // anyone to overwrite your entire database.

  "rules": {
    ".read": true
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

more information about this process:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/insecure-rules#open_access

I've noticed that you use user authentication.
In this case, I recommend that you not only put true in the rules file but give access only to an authenticated user, this creates a more secure state that prevents other people from accessing and changing the database. Here's how:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "some_path": {
      "$uid": {
        // Allow only authenticated content owners access to their data
        ".read": "request.auth.uid == uid"
        ".write": "request.auth.uid == uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Link for more details:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/insecure-rules#content-owner-only_1